# How browsers cache files and images?

Tags: caching, browser

As far as I know, while someone visits a website for the first time, some files and images will save for next times to load faster.
But how browser cache images and files?
Does browser only cache local files? for example: `/images/....` OR files or images which starts with `http` will be cached too?

90% of my images and files starts with : `http://www.mysite.com/images/...`
Is it a bad practice?

Comment: AFAIK the way you reference resources doesn't matter. Browser will check if resource changed - and not reload if it determines it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/images/....

http://www.mysite.com/images/...
```

both are the same, web browser will cache files when your images will change..